# Spark sql, why fallback to SizeInBytesOnlyStatsPlanVisitor when visitWithCTE in BasicStatsPlanVisitor？

Tags: apache-spark-sql, cost-based-optimizer, cbo

I'm wondering why visiting WithCTE will fallback to SizeInBytesOnlyStatsPlanVisitor.
This will absolutely reduce precision of estimation.
I'm reading the github apache spark code, but still cannot figure out why. Can anyone help me?

[apache spark, master branch, BasicStatsPlanVisitor.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/statsEstimation/BasicStatsPlanVisitor.scala)